# Why aren't my themes showing up in Ubuntu 20.04 Tweaks?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, themes, gtk, gnome-tweaks

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I have not upgraded from a previous LTS version, it's a completely fresh install.

I downloaded `dconf` and all its extensions, and in Tweaks, my user theme shells tab no longer has the triangle which tells you they are disabled and you are now able to select different shells.

In the past, when I had 18.04 LTS, I had to create a `themes` folder and add it to the home directory and from memory the `/user/share` folder as well for the themes to work.

I created the the `themes` folder in my home directory in 20.4.2 and they do not show up in Tweaks, other than the themes that are already there. From what I can see, there no longer is a `user/share` folder, like there used to be. All I see are links to the `themes` folder.

So where do I need to place my themes, and in which folder or folders? I cannot seem to find a straightforward answer here after looking at various answers.

Comment: They should be in `~/.themes` not `~/themes` (mind the dot). Try moving themes in `~/.themes` and then close and reopen Tweaks.

Comment: Your right, that was a silly thing to miss actually. Have to log out and log back in i think. There is something else that i have just realised as well. The themes that are visible have gtk2 and gtk3 folders in them, most of the themes i have do not have those folders in them. They worked fine in ubuntu 18.04. Stands to reason they should work on 20.04.2

Comment: It didn't work. There is something missing. I will try downloading and installing themes from scratch instead of copying. We'll see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `/users/share/themes` folder, but there is a `/usr/share/themes`. You could try that if `~/.themes` didn't work for you.

Comment: I think i'm missing some theme engines. Placing them in the above mentioned folders should work.

Comment: The only thing that worked was 2 icon themes which i placed in the /usr/share/icons folder. I just checked my gnome version which is 3.36.9. That may have something to do with it but it doesn't solve the issue really. I just tried a few gnome shell icons for gnome 3.30 and still nothing. I'm thinking if i downgrade to a lower gnome version things may not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste a theme in ~/.themes, you should look for it in Applications part of Tweaks and it was at the top of the window but in the new version of Tweaks, Applications part is located below (which is written `Legacy Applications`) :[image]

So you must be able to see the added theme in the list. 
**Note that when adding the theme, close Tweaks (if open) and open it again.**